# Which Linux distro uses Linux kernel as is with no modification

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm trying to do some learning with Linux kernel and as you all know there is nothing better than playing with the code itself, Can you please let me know which one of the Linux distros is the easiest to work with? In other words, As far as I know Ubuntu for example modify the kernel for their distro, so the question again, which distro is using the Linux kernel as is with no modification?

Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: You could always download the main source release and compile it yourself. If you want to learn about kernel programming you're going to have to know how to compile it anyway.

Comment: Probably none of them :-). _All_ distros provide the source, though.

Comment: ArchLinux? :)  It's really easy to compile a kernel with ABS and it auto downloads the patches they've used and you can compile without them anyways.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to no-frills (no external patches to the kernel) have a look at Slackware.  Or follow "Linux from Scratch", that's as bare-bones as it gets.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about LFS as well, I hoped there is more direct easy way :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start playing with the Linux kernel, I'd recommend a distribution which makes it particularily easy to compile the kernel yourself. Although I cannot provide detailed guidance, Gentoo seems to do so (although gentoo has other drawbacks, I don't know a single person in real life who actually used gentoo for more than two years).

I would not try and look for distributions not modifying the kernel, it's probably not worth the effort. Patches will probably be minor compared to the overall size of the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily run Ubuntu for example with a vanilla kernel by following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild.